# Como fixar botão no fundo de um página sem se mover?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

Tenho uma página com `navbar` e com uma `div` que contém um logo, um parágrafo com texto e depois um botão, tudo na mesma `div`, cada componente abaixo da outra na ordem referida anteriormente.

A minha questão é, a descrição não sou eu que vou fazer e consequentemente não sei o tamanho que vai ter, sei que não vai ser nada muito elaborado mas ainda assim queria perguntar se é possível fazer com que o botão abaixo da descrição não se mova, quando se diminui ou aumenta a descrição. Ou seja, cada vez que diminuo a descrição ele vem para cima e cada vez que aumento ele vai para baixo.

Já experimentei com `overflow: hidden`, e várias outras formas que fui vendo aqui no Stackoverflow e no Google, mas até agora não encontrei nada que funcionasse.

```css
.desc-div{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;

}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.desc {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    padding: 2%;
}

.desc-div2 {
    height: 100%;
}


.desc-div2 svg {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2001;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-div header pt-lg-8 align-items-center"> 
    <div class="desc-div2 container-fluid align-items-center">
        <img class="logo" src="/img/logo.svg">
        <p class="desc"><%= __('Hi hello my name is, and I live next door...............................') %></p>
        <a>
            <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 30 28" xml:space="preserve">
                <path fill="#D9BD45" d="M28.97,20.884c0.558,0,1.03,0.475,1.03,1.035v5.047C30,27.569,29.528,28,28.97,28H1.028 C0.472,28,0,27.569,0,26.965v-5.047c0-0.559,0.472-1.035,1.028-1.035H28.97z"/>
                <path fill="#D9BD45" d="M28.496,0.179L15,10.61L1.504,0.179C0.894-0.271,0,0.179,0,0.955V6.6c0,0.288,0.162,0.655,0.284,0.737 L15,18.231L29.716,7.337C29.838,7.256,30,6.888,30,6.6V0.955C30,0.179,29.106-0.271,28.496,0.179z"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, se o botão não se mover para baixo o botão vai sobrepor o conteúdo da descrição conforme for aumentado. É realmente isso que você quer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` com `bottom: 15px` no svg que ele irá ficar fixo na parte de baixo da tela, sem sofrer influência do parágrafo ou de outro elemento, porque ficará posicionado de forma absoluta dentro da div.

*Esse `15px` no bottom você coloca o valor que quiser e achar melhor para dar um espaçamento da parte de baixo.*

Agora, é preciso adicionar...

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

...para que a div consiga ter a altura de 100%, como você quer em `min-height: 100%;`. Também não vejo função para a tag `<svg>` estar dentro desse `<a>`. Também não precisa do `margin-left: 15px` no svg, por isso deixei comentado essa linha no CSS abaixo:

```css
html, body{
   background: #000;
   height: 100%;
}

.desc-div{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;

}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

.desc {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    padding: 2%;
}

.desc-div2 {
    height: 100%;
}


.desc-div2 svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2001;
    /*margin-left: 15px; removido */
    bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-div header pt-lg-8 align-items-center"> 
    <div class="desc-div2 container-fluid align-items-center">
        <img class="logo" src="/img/logo.svg">
        <p class="desc">Hi hello my name is, and I live next door</p>
         <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 30 28" xml:space="preserve">
             <path fill="#D9BD45" d="M28.97,20.884c0.558,0,1.03,0.475,1.03,1.035v5.047C30,27.569,29.528,28,28.97,28H1.028 C0.472,28,0,27.569,0,26.965v-5.047c0-0.559,0.472-1.035,1.028-1.035H28.97z"/>
             <path fill="#D9BD45" d="M28.496,0.179L15,10.61L1.504,0.179C0.894-0.271,0,0.179,0,0.955V6.6c0,0.288,0.162,0.655,0.284,0.737 L15,18.231L29.716,7.337C29.838,7.256,30,6.888,30,6.6V0.955C30,0.179,29.106-0.271,28.496,0.179z"/>
         </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```